# Data imputation for incorrect answers

Tags: missing-data, data-imputation, reliability

**Problem**: I have an MCQ language proficiency test completed by 147 participants. 6 questions were never answered correctly by all participants, which left 30% of the test data as NA. I want to assess the reliability of the test using Omega or Cronbach’s Alpha. However, these reliability measures do not include the items with no variability i.e., the 6 never-correctly answered questions, which may bias the coefficients.

**Questions**:

1. Do you recommend that I use data imputation in this case? Note that I think the data was missing because the participants have limited language skills which did not allow them to correctly answer the 6 questions.
2. If you do not recommended imputation, what is the best available solution?

I would be thankful for you help.

Answer (score 0):

#### Theoretical Problem

I think imputation here would be extremely problematic given this is data that has severely structural causes that can't be easily remedied. Additionally, you have already mentioned the issue with a lack of variance. You have a missing constant across columns that can't be accounted for by simply imputing them, especially if your other items measure different aspects of whatever construct you are trying to look at. Imputation at the minimum has to draw from prior data, and here you don't have any to model it off.

The best solution is to try to find out why they didn't answer these questions and it seems you have a plausible cause. You can simply explain in your limitations that this occurred and that you tried to remedy it as best as possible by using what available information you have, and may use a form with multiple languages, simpler language, etc. to not replicate this problem. Simply imputing these values won't fix the matter and may actually cause more harm.

An article on missingness I often cite can be seen below:

[On the Joys of Missing Data, Little et al., 2014](https://watermark.silverchair.com/jst048.pdf?token=AQECAHi208BE49Ooan9kkhW_Ercy7Dm3ZL_9Cf3qfKAc485ysgAAAscwggLDBgkqhkiG9w0BBwagggK0MIICsAIBADCCAqkGCSqGSIb3DQEHATAeBglghkgBZQMEAS4wEQQMcHR29F2no0uqgvUgAgEQgIICeulmry12-agLefr6iq6i1x3YizwsIlt_6yHekIq7K5qVv59ftdW9tOYs9GRKiT9ismsMksTOQSlgvFacDBdB-fhSgDag9NQqNRsS55TorrHAsoWCl52XW5tX9rlI2iQduJGn3t83L7GDiOinhp32AsGye7KMljQ6KPDUKJ2h1GSmWMlJr3O_43nc6FeGebDfQLC1WIeJTJab81TYB6uoYJI3dCMdLYZ7hTrmQSfCeo5-odpUEAhRbXX2DaeSOQ24vpHNsLUnXWZb_EA2F-Idw9cH0bD1yN4jqcmL4WzWwECjrDGOCaRH3IxmY-eXkFDAWCY2YHOFrnRIKOEH0kVpIyBiI-bPFICn-MFrNAnWt_7xofX6mCt6DWHWGa0SHDuEJFQDIllt36nLrIAJFqxgQ13weOT-eF0nX0BJWo-j_9zoaGq3QuK938i1sqpXVecdmowI1wUvrbsScqr3m9_oYng0HKFsxgF6n5b7bF4rnpGIjF-W7iUBj1t4KVNnWrkeNYH1b3B_ntykzaRyqRmhS_or8welTQwSYi8MN-cDukVpQjOFIU94_6oVmMdWbR6_k_xdY3JJzWwohm0F-poBCys770x7WGWiRu4yPIXjS3tfLsP39gz-73H8T6oeisKQKl7DbiGjyQ2HIjpVrl1aZY-LEMSPWaBTzqvbTiA9EPJY1G0IfhDlHA4-0xYL3-uoFHfd1uF283KLkXCe4yC3VX4d246j-DaZ13dNAgag-5614jyw_Ku3yBjXeH8wwdicFG7PQrkg5eruWq68jTuE3mprT-XFEmWymsyrTjn9pL7bocWFNsZjjjrQlBEiGpi0M6Msv1Jqhd8rbv4)

#### Practical Problem

The other issue is that you will simply not be able to do this if you resort to techniques like multiple imputation, which is typically considered more accurate than older versions of imputation methods. Below I take the famous Holzinger Swineford data, create an entire missing column, impute it, then pool the data together.

```
#### Save Holzinger Data with Missing Column ####
holz <- HolzingerSwineford1939 %>%
  as_tibble() %>% 
  select(7:15) %>% 
  mutate(x10 = rep(NA,301))

#### Impute ####
imp <- mice(holz,
            m=5)
comp.data <- complete(imp)
```

If you print the column that had missing data:

```
comp.data %>% 
  select(x10)
```

You'll notice something peculiar...the data is still missing.

```
    x10
1    NA
2    NA
3    NA
4    NA
5    NA
6    NA
7    NA
8    NA
9    NA
10   NA
11   NA
12   NA
13   NA
14   NA
15   NA
16   NA
17   NA
18   NA
19   NA
20   NA
21   NA
22   NA
23   NA
24   NA
25   NA
26   NA
27   NA
28   NA
29   NA
30   NA
31   NA
32   NA
33   NA
34   NA
35   NA
36   NA
37   NA
38   NA
39   NA
40   NA
41   NA
42   NA
43   NA
44   NA
45   NA
46   NA
47   NA
48   NA
49   NA
50   NA
51   NA
52   NA
53   NA
54   NA
55   NA
56   NA
57   NA
58   NA
59   NA
60   NA
61   NA
62   NA
63   NA
64   NA
65   NA
66   NA
67   NA
68   NA
69   NA
70   NA
71   NA
72   NA
73   NA
74   NA
75   NA
76   NA
77   NA
78   NA
79   NA
80   NA
81   NA
82   NA
83   NA
84   NA
85   NA
86   NA
87   NA
88   NA
89   NA
90   NA
91   NA
92   NA
93   NA
94   NA
95   NA
96   NA
97   NA
98   NA
99   NA
100  NA
101  NA
102  NA
103  NA
104  NA
105  NA
106  NA
107  NA
108  NA
109  NA
110  NA
111  NA
112  NA
113  NA
114  NA
115  NA
116  NA
117  NA
118  NA
119  NA
120  NA
121  NA
122  NA
123  NA
124  NA
125  NA
126  NA
127  NA
128  NA
129  NA
130  NA
131  NA
132  NA
133  NA
134  NA
135  NA
136  NA
137  NA
138  NA
139  NA
140  NA
141  NA
142  NA
143  NA
144  NA
145  NA
146  NA
147  NA
148  NA
149  NA
150  NA
151  NA
152  NA
153  NA
154  NA
155  NA
156  NA
157  NA
158  NA
159  NA
160  NA
161  NA
162  NA
163  NA
164  NA
165  NA
166  NA
167  NA
168  NA
169  NA
170  NA
171  NA
172  NA
173  NA
174  NA
175  NA
176  NA
177  NA
178  NA
179  NA
180  NA
181  NA
182  NA
183  NA
184  NA
185  NA
186  NA
187  NA
188  NA
189  NA
190  NA
191  NA
192  NA
193  NA
194  NA
195  NA
196  NA
197  NA
198  NA
199  NA
200  NA
201  NA
202  NA
203  NA
204  NA
205  NA
206  NA
207  NA
208  NA
209  NA
210  NA
211  NA
212  NA
213  NA
214  NA
215  NA
216  NA
217  NA
218  NA
219  NA
220  NA
221  NA
222  NA
223  NA
224  NA
225  NA
226  NA
227  NA
228  NA
229  NA
230  NA
231  NA
232  NA
233  NA
234  NA
235  NA
236  NA
237  NA
238  NA
239  NA
240  NA
241  NA
242  NA
243  NA
244  NA
245  NA
246  NA
247  NA
248  NA
249  NA
250  NA
251  NA
252  NA
253  NA
254  NA
255  NA
256  NA
257  NA
258  NA
259  NA
260  NA
261  NA
262  NA
263  NA
264  NA
265  NA
266  NA
267  NA
268  NA
269  NA
270  NA
271  NA
272  NA
273  NA
274  NA
275  NA
276  NA
277  NA
278  NA
279  NA
280  NA
281  NA
282  NA
283  NA
284  NA
285  NA
286  NA
287  NA
288  NA
289  NA
290  NA
291  NA
292  NA
293  NA
294  NA
295  NA
296  NA
297  NA
298  NA
299  NA
300  NA
301  NA
```

Comment: Thank you a lot for your informative answer! Much appreciated.

Comment: No problem. I have edited my answer to also include a practical example of why this doesn't work.